# Were post-* icons remove in core-icons/social-icons.html?

Tags: polymer

Previously (v0.5.2) core-icons/social-icons.html was defining:

- post-facebook
- post-twitter
- post-gplus

This doesn't seem to be the case in v0.5.4 anymore.

Are there any other icons subject to removal?

Thanks,

F.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The open source material icons do not include the post-* icons, and 0.5.3/4 rebased on the open source set.

Comment: Have they been moved somewhere else?

Comment: I wasn't able to find them elsewhere, I created a project to provide these icons for my apps dependent on them.

https://github.com/vanxrice/social-post-icons